# Append a word after matching a string from looped list in data frame with external lists to new column in same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

I want to loop over a pandas data frame where each row has a list of strings. But for each row, I want to cross-reference it with another set of lists with predefined strings. If the predefined string within the external lists matches with the string in the row, I want to append the matching string to a new column with the same index as the looped over row. If no string matches then a generic string must be appended to the column with the same index as the looped over row. Once all the rows(1207 to be exact) have been looped over, the column with the appended words must match the number of rows.

```
#these are the predefined lists
    traffic=['stationary','congest','traffic','slow','heavi','bumper','flow','spectate','emergm','jam','visibl'] #predefined list of strings
    accident=['outsur','accid','avoid','crash','overturn','massiv','fatalmov','roll'] #predefined list of strings
    crime=['shootout','lawnessness','robbery','fire','n1shoot','rob','mug','killed','kill','scene','lawness'] #predefined list of strings

    #this is the code I have already tried  

        for x in test['text']:
                for y in x:
                    if y in traffic:
                        test['type1']=('traffic')
                        break
                    if y in crime:
                        test['type1']=('crime')
                        break
                    if y in accident:
                        test['type1']=('accident')
                        break
                    else:
                        test['type1']=('ignore')
                        break

Below is a sample of my data frame
Dataframe name is test
[original dataframe][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZML4.png

from what I have tried this is the output

[Output of code in dataframe][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwj1g.png
```

Comment: Please provide a sample code here as opposed to an image to make easier for other people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a simpler way for you to run such comparison. The order was not clear which list should be compared first, but below is one way:

*PS: Created a sample data*:

```py
x =[
    [['report','shootout','midrand','n1','north','slow']],
    [['jhbtraffic','lioght','out','citi','deep']],
    [['jhbtraffic','light','out','booysen','booysen']]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['text'])

df
Out[2]:
    text
0   [report, shootout, midrand, n1, north, slow]
1   [jhbtraffic, lioght, out, citi, deep]
2   [jhbtraffic, light, out, booysen, booysen]
```

Actual solution:

```py
### get matched strings per row
matched = df['text'].apply(lambda x: [a for  a in x for i in crime+accident+traffic if i==a ])

### merge to the original dataset
df.join(pd.DataFrame(matched.tolist(), index= df.index)).fillna('ignored')

Out[1]:
    text                                            0           1
0   [report, shootout, midrand, n1, north, slow]    shootout    slow
1   [jhbtraffic, lioght, out, citi, deep]   ignored     ignored
2   [jhbtraffic, light, out, booysen, booysen]  ignored     ignored
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been a big help:)

Comment: @HoboKnoxDaOddGod Anytime! Feel free to accept the answer in case it does reply to what you asked.